# How do I properly force a Git add?

Tags: git

I want to push my local files, and have them on a remote repo in openshift, without having to deal with merge conflicts. I just want my local files to be uploaded

Comment: So you want to clobber the changes others may have made? Do you even know what git is _for_? There are options to `git push` that are relevant to your interests, but if you have to ask SO to find them for you then nothing good is likely to come out of you making use of them.

Comment: First "git add ." and git commit -a -m "All", the result is: nothing to commit, working directory clean,  I just want my ALL local files to be uploaded

Comment: Chris Kitching, thanks, I'm doing a test, not hurt anyone, I understand it's git, ( I just want my ALL local files to be uploaded)

Comment: Is your working directory the root of your git repo? `add .` only adds files under this one.
`commit -a` auto-adds all tracked files, but will not add new files.
Does your repo have a .gitignore that causes some of your files to be ignored?

Comment: Chris Kitching, thanks, yes, is root, .gitignore contains .DS_Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add the ads the files to the repository.
Once you added your files you can then `pull (fetch+merge)` changes from your server.

If you will have conflicts at this time you can always go back (abort merge) and then choose `ours` as the merge strategies.

> ***`ours`***
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, ***effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches***.
>
> It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the `-Xours` option to the recursive merge strategy.
>
> ***ours merge strategy, does not even look at what the other tree contains at all.***
>
> ***It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it.***